# Problem creating Facebook application with heroku

Tags: ruby, facebook, heroku

I am trying to create a canvas Facebook application.

I have created Heroku application written in ruby via Facebook.

Creating the application I followed the steps of these guides:

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/configuring-your-facebook-app-as-a-canvas-page

After following these steps when I go to the [application](https://apps.facebook.com/canihazmilk/) it says

> Not Found

When I put it in Facebook's Object Debugger it says:

> Extraneous Property - Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:site_url.

How can I fix this?

Thanks,

Oded

Comment: This is being tracked as a bug here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/268945469795682

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas app **POST's** to '/'.

The heroku template is expecting **GET**.

See the following to accept both GET and POST's:
http://ujihisa.blogspot.com/2009/11/accepting-both-get-and-post-method-in.html

Change

```
get '/' do ...
```

to...

```
def get_or_post(path, opts={}, &block)
  get(path, opts, &block)
  post(path, opts, &block)
end

get_or_post '/' do...
```

Comment: Wow you just solved an major bug with facebook's sample app congrats!

Comment: @Oded +1. Sadly, they are not rare.